# What is the best way to avoid floating point calculation error here?

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have two variables a and b. First variable contains a simple float in string format. Second variable contains another simple float. I need to divide those and multiply with a constant. Since the numbers are simple and I require the result for a comparison operation, I need the calculation to be error free. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
public class FloatTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a ="5";
        float b =(float) 4.8;
        float r = Float.valueOf(a)*24/b;
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

```
result: 24.999998
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result appears to be error-free, in binary. You're assuming that 48/10 can be expressed exactly ("simple number"). That's true in decimal digits, but not in bits. No surprise, really: `10` is not a power of 2, so dividing by 10 is not  a simple matter of moving the point in a floating-point number.

If you need exact numbers, don't use an finite-precision format like `Float`. A `Decimal` type would be more appropriate.

Comment: How does a `Decimal` type provide an exact number for ⅓?

Comment: By the way, a better term than “finite” to expression the different between, say, the `double` format and the `BigDecimal` format, is “fixed.” The `double` format has a fixed precision. The `BigDecimal` format has an arbitrary precision. No format can have infinite precision; they are all finite.

Comment: I understand now that I have to accept the error. And I somewhere found a method that works in most of the cases in spite of the error. While comparing 2 floats I have to use something like: `abs(x-y)<0.00001` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use John L. Gustafson's "unums", an alterative to floats.  See https://posithub.org/about, for example.  Also, per IEEE, you *should* (many implementations have bugs or lack of support) be able to use the exceptions--see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=concepts-floating-point-exceptions for example.